# NoSuchMethodError: ConfigurationManager.addConfigurationProvider while deploying Struts 2 application on Apache Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

The application runs fine on the local machine.

On the server I have JDK-1.7 and Tomcat 8. It is giving me the below error in `localhost` logs. The jar exists in the `lib` directory of the application.

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter struts2
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ConfigurationProvider;)V
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_DefaultProperties(Dispatcher.java:296)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:396)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when i switched to tomcat7 instead of tomcat8 , the application worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> The jar exists in the lib directory of the application

Which Jar ? Because I guess you're referring to the `struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar`, that contains the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter you're using, but you also need the `xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar` (or whatever your version is), that contains the other methods the filter refers to

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a mismatch in jar version as it is able to find the class file within that jar but not method with below signature in class ConfigurationManager

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.addConfigurationProvider (Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ConfigurationProvider;)
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager` is in the `xwork*.jar` and it doesn't have a method `addConfigurationProvider()`. If your app

> runs fine on local machine

then you have another jar with the same name file somewhere on the server lib. But this file has a different version. Make sure you have the same version for `struts2-core*.jar` and `xwork-core*.jar`.

This is the link where you can [download](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts23241) all required libraries.

Put necessary libraries to the `WEB-INF/lib` and clean up the server classpath.